# Which make implicit rules are invoked when there is only a target specified with no (explicit) prerequisites?

Tags: makefile

I have the source file `even_odd_list.c` in the `src` directory. Here is the `makefile` I am experimenting with

```
VPATH = src include
CPPFLAGS = -I include

even_odd_list:
```

I have called `make -pn` to examine all the implicit rules, but I don't see one that seems to apply.

What am I missing? I would appreciate an explanation of the logical flow that make is executing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make will match this implicit rule (found by examining `make -pf/def/null`):

```
%: %.c
#  commands to execute (built-in):
        $(LINK.c) $^ $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS) -o $@
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I also wanted to know why. After doing more digging and examining the output from make -d I started looking more into implicit prerequisites.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "why"; you didn't ask any other question.  Why what?  Make chooses that rule because (a) there's no recipe defined for that target in the makefile, and (b) the `%` pattern in the rule matches the target you want to build (`%` matches everything of course), and (c) the prerequisite for that rule `%.c` (since `%` matches `even_odd_list` then `%.c` matches `even_odd_list.c`) exists.  So make uses that rule.

Comment: I could have stated it better. I am studying from a book that includes the source files as prerequisites, so I assumed this was necessary, but it seems now that it is redundant. The source is an implied prerequisite; this makes perfect sense. In the make file that I posted I wanted to know how the target matched with the rule that you specified. With knowledge of the implied prerequisite it seems clear.

Comment: If you're writing your own explicit rule, with a recipe, then you have to provide all the prerequisites yourself including the `.c` file.  If you are using implicit rules, then make will choose the "best" implicit rule (the exact algorithm is described in the GNU make manual) based on the files it has available, or knows how to build.  In that case it typically knows at least one of the prerequisites already since it's described in the implicit rule.

Answer (score 2):

The fact that was overlooked here, was how make matches targets to implicit rules. In this case there is no prerequisite specified, but make will match an implicit rule if a prerequisite for the rule exist or ought to exist and can be made. When a prerequisites for a matching implicit rule exist and is not specified it is considered a implicit prerequisite.

So, the first rule to match is:

```
%: %.c
#  commands to execute (built-in):
        $(LINK.c) $^ $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS) -o $@
```

This page has more info http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Using-Implicit.html.

Using `make -d` will show the steps make is executing. Here is the relevant output for this example:

```
Updating goal targets....
Considering target file `even_odd_list'.
 File `even_odd_list' does not exist.
 Looking for an implicit rule for `even_odd_list'.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `even_odd_list'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `even_odd_list.o'.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `even_odd_list'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `even_odd_list.c'.
 Found prerequisite `even_odd_list.c' as VPATH `src/even_odd_list.c'
 Found an implicit rule for `even_odd_list'.
  Considering target file `even_odd_list.c'.
   Looking for an implicit rule for `even_odd_list.c'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `even_odd_list'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite `even_odd_list.y'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `even_odd_list'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite `even_odd_list.l'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `even_odd_list'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite `even_odd_list.w'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `even_odd_list'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite `even_odd_list.w'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `even_odd_list.c'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite `even_odd_list.c,v'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `even_odd_list.c'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite `RCS/even_odd_list.c,v'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `even_odd_list.c'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite `RCS/even_odd_list.c'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `even_odd_list.c'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite `s.even_odd_list.c'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `even_odd_list.c'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite `SCCS/s.even_odd_list.c'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `even_odd_list'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite `even_odd_list.y'.
   Looking for a rule with intermediate file `even_odd_list.y'.
    Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `even_odd_list.y'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `even_odd_list.y,v'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `even_odd_list.y'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `RCS/even_odd_list.y,v'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `even_odd_list.y'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `RCS/even_odd_list.y'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `even_odd_list.y'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `s.even_odd_list.y'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `even_odd_list.y'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `SCCS/s.even_odd_list.y'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `even_odd_list'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite `even_odd_list.l'.
   Looking for a rule with intermediate file `even_odd_list.l'.
    Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `even_odd_list.l'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `even_odd_list.l,v'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `even_odd_list.l'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `RCS/even_odd_list.l,v'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `even_odd_list.l'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `RCS/even_odd_list.l'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `even_odd_list.l'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `s.even_odd_list.l'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `even_odd_list.l'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `SCCS/s.even_odd_list.l'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `even_odd_list'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite `even_odd_list.w'.
   Looking for a rule with intermediate file `even_odd_list.w'.
    Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `even_odd_list.w'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `even_odd_list.w,v'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `even_odd_list.w'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `RCS/even_odd_list.w,v'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `even_odd_list.w'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `RCS/even_odd_list.w'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `even_odd_list.w'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `s.even_odd_list.w'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `even_odd_list.w'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `SCCS/s.even_odd_list.w'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `even_odd_list'.
   Rejecting impossible implicit prerequisite `even_odd_list.w'.
   No implicit rule found for `even_odd_list.c'.
   Finished prerequisites of target file `even_odd_list.c'.
  No need to remake target `even_odd_list.c'; using VPATH name `src/even_odd_list.c'.
 Finished prerequisites of target file `even_odd_list'.
Must remake target `even_odd_list'.
cc  -I include   src/even_odd_list.c   -o even_odd_list
Putting child 0x085fbe90 (even_odd_list) PID 24853 on the chain.
Live child 0x085fbe90 (even_odd_list) PID 24853 
Reaping winning child 0x085fbe90 PID 24853 
Removing child 0x085fbe90 PID 24853 from chain.
Successfully remade target file `even_odd_list'.
```